How to have powershell's autocomplete not insert a function's opening parenthesis?
If you enter anything that autocompletes to a .net function name, for example enter [Io.File]::A and hit tab, it autocompletes to [Io.File]::AppendAllLines(. How do you have it not insert the function's opening parenthesis?

The PowerShell repo on GitHub might be the best place to ask this. https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues

I'm just curious why you would want that? Functions have the opening parenthesis to distinguish them from properties that don't have them. If you continue pressing Tab you can cycle through all properties/functions and pressing Ctrl+Space after :: will show you all available properties and functions.
